# How to set version of a Qt application (made by QtIF)?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qt5, qtif

Just noticed a `File version` (4.2.0.0) from a Qt application, when mouse goes over the file. However that seems to be the [QtIF](https://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/index.html) version, not my application version.

How to set that (mouser over) version of a Qt application (made by QtIF)?

[image]

Comment: But what if to set `version` in installer configuration file, while it's creation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be considered the expected behavior (f.ex. when used as an online installer), as the installer is able to install multiple versions of your program and/or upgrade your installation once a new version of your software becomes available. So, the installer is not directly related to a specific version of your software. See for example the Qt installer itself.

If you really want to control the version number, you should [compile the installer from source](https://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/ifw-getting-started.html) and [change the version string of the installer itself](https://code.qt.io/cgit/installer-framework/installer-framework.git/tree/installerfw.pri#n6) by slightly modifying the source code. In case you use the installer as a pure offline installer, this may indeed be appropriate.

Comment: Wondering what others think about this behavior. I don't understand why this would be the desired behavior.

Comment: I think it depends on which installer concept you use: an offline (traditional) vs an online installer. QtIF is primarily an online orientated approach. The same installer can be used to install different versions of your software. The installer is more a "maintenance" tool in this case. In this case, the version of the installer is the version of the maintenance tool, and not the version of your actual software (as it is not uniquely defined).

Comment: Well, I'm using it offline so far. Considering to use it online in the future. Wondering if you can add a reference for "QtIF is **primarily** an online orientated approach", unless is your opinion

Comment: "primarily" is indeed somewhat opinion based and not directly stated as such. However, the behaviour of the version number may suggests so and even the offline installer is able to connect to an update repository, making it an hybrid installer. Off course, I agree with you that the desired behaviour of the installer version number is subject to discussion. If you use it as an offline installer only, I agree that this behaviour is rather undesirable. In this case, recompiling QtIF with your version number may be an option, as stated in the answer. Let's hope that others join the discussion.

Comment: I tried to nuance my answer. The "why" part of my answer is somewhat opinion based (and rather off topic on SO).